# Get all not NULL column names from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following columns: F1, F2, ...F10
Some of these columns contain only NULLS, let's say they are F2 and F7.
How can I get a string with the names of these columns, I would like to get 'F2,F7' as a return value. 
This is a temporary table and column names and the number of columns is unknown. I need some very generic function to extract the column names containing NULLs

NOTE:
I know it is fairy easy in Oracle using some system objects (i.e. all_tab_columns, etc), not sure if possible in SQL Server as well.

Thank you.

Comment: You actually should redesign your table. That is NOT how you do it

Comment: Why should I redesign the table? This is not a question about table structure, it is rather related to table NULL values

Comment: You can use UNPIVOT and the XML contcat trick.

Comment: Interesting, can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 4):

To **list all non-nullable columns** in the 'dbo.Employee' Table in the database, run the following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG AS Database_Name, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'Employee'
AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you need this but something like this should help you

```
Select CASE WHEN Len(res) > 0 THEN LEFT(res, Len(res) - 1) ELSE '' END AS result
From 
(
select case when Count(F1)= 0 then 'F1,' else '' End +
       case when Count(F2)= 0 then 'F2,' else '' End +
       case when Count(F3)= 0 then 'F3,' else '' End +
            .....
       case when Count(F10)= 0 then 'F10,' else '' End 
       End as res
From yourtable
) A
```

Here is dynamic approach that works for unknown column names

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) =''

SET @sql = ' Select CASE WHEN Len(res) > 0 THEN LEFT(res, Len(res) - 1) ELSE '''' END AS result
From 
(
select'
SET @sql += (SELECT ' case when Count(' + COLUMN_NAME + ')= 0 then ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ','' else '''' End+'
             FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
             WHERE  table_name = 'TableA'
             FOR xml path (''))
SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, Len(@sql) - 1)
SET @sql += ' From yourtable ) A (res)'

--SELECT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: @vkp - Probably you should say why it will not work to improve my answer

Comment: problem1-case returns a value on the first true condition, other conditions will be ignored. problem 2- you should use `count(case when f1 is not null then 1 end) = 0`

Comment: I didn't mention this: this is a temporary table and column names and the number of columns is unknown. I need some very generic function to extract the column names containing NULLs

Comment: @vkp - Problem1 agreed and updated.. regarding problem2 how it differs from `COUNT(F1)`

Comment: sorry about problem 2.. the updated query should work well.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help but as I mentioned above, the column names are unknown. Need some different approach.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work... You use an aggregate function (COUNT) without a GROUP BY clause. I added the clause but result is still null

Comment: @M.R. - I think you have added a non aggregate column to the above query can you post what ever query that generated this error

Comment: Select CASE WHEN Len(res) > 0 THEN LEFT(res, Len(res) - 1) ELSE '' END AS result From (select(SELECT case when

Comment: Count(COLUMN_NAME)= 0 then COLUMN_NAME + ',' else '' End FROM

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  table_name = 'cr_data1'

Comment: GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME FOR xml path ('')) From cr_data1 ) A (res)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.name, c.name, c.is_nullable 
FROM sys.tables t 
JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'YourTableNameHere'
  AND c.is_nullable = 0
```

If you are on MS SQL Server and trying to avoid INFORMATION_SCHEMA.